# How to check if the MPI already installed on my machine

Tags: mpi

I need to know how to check if MPI is already installed on my machine, and if not how much time it takes to be installed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling tells me that the command to install MPI is `sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc`. Enter that command. If it is already installed, it will tell you. If not, it will tell you how much data needs to be downloaded. Then the data needs to be unpacked and the various files copied to their destination. Finally, installation scripts need to run.

If you don't like the amount of stuff that needs to be downloaded and/or installed, you get the chance to cancel the installation.

In my experience, even large packages rarely take more than a minute to install.

Answer (score 10):

Run the command:

```
ompi_info
```

It will give you the description of your mpi library if installed.